# index returning -1 jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

So why is this? Very confused...Thanks!

`$('#navigation ul li a:first').index($('#navigation ul li a')) >> returns 0 expect 0`

`$('#navigation ul li a:last').index($('#navigation ul li a'))  >> returns -1 expect 19`

`$('#navigation ul li a').eq(2).index($('#navigation ul li a')) >> returns -1 expect 2`

UPDATE: here are some html, it's my pagination code:

```
        <div id="navigation">
            <ul> 
                <li><a class="current" href="#1-1">1</a></li> 
                <li><a class="" href="#1-2">2</a></li>
                <li><a class="" href="#1-3">3</a></li> 
                <li><a class="" href="#1-4">4</a></li>
                <li><a class="" href="#1-5">5</a></li> 
                <li><a class="" href="#1-6">6</a></li>
                <li><a class="" href="#1-7">7</a></li>
                <li><a class="" href="#1-8">8</a></li>
                <li><a class="" href="#1-9">9</a></li>
                <li><a class="" href="#1-10">10</a></li>
                <li><a class="" href="#1-11">11</a></li>
                <li><a class="" href="#1-12">12</a></li>
                <li><a class="" href="#1-13">13</a></li>
                <li><a class="" href="#1-14">14</a></li>
                <li><a class="" href="#1-15">15</a></li>
                <li><a class="" href="#1-16">16</a></li>
                <li><a class="" href="#1-17">17</a></li>
                <li><a class="" href="#1-18">18</a></li>
                <li><a class="" href="#1-19">19</a></li>
                <li><a class="" href="#1-20">20</a></li>                  
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Comment: You need to give a little more than that... some code perhaps... and some html...

Comment: Could you post that in jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: You're calling `index` on the wrong array: it returns the index of the element in the array you're calling `index` on.

Comment: thanks. what's the right way then? i also did: `$('#navigation ul li a:last').parent().index() >>returns -1 expect 20`

Comment: The way you had it would have been correct if you just passed a selector string instead of a jQuery object, like this: `$('#navigation ul li a:last').index('#navigation ul li a')`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to reverse your selectors:

```
alert($('#navigation ul li a').index($('#navigation ul li a:first')));   // 0
alert($('#navigation ul li a').index($('#navigation ul li a:last')));    // 19
alert($('#navigation ul li a').index($('#navigation ul li a').eq(2)));   // 2
```

**[SEE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/evusid)**

Answer (score 3):

-1 means that element wasn't found by [index()](http://api.jquery.com/index/)

try indexing the list items instead of anchors as they are on the same level

```
var listItems = $('#navigation ul li');

$('#navigation ul li:first').index(listItems);  
$('#navigation ul li:last').index(listItems);   
$('#navigation ul li').eq(2).index(listItems);
```

Comment: '$('#navigation ul li:last').index() returns -1 expected 19' :( also did `$all = $('navigation ul li'); $('navigation ul li:last').index($all) >>returns -1 expected 19`